# Path Analyzer Tracking Pixel

Tags: tracking, path-analyzer

I am interested in using Path Analyzer. I was told that we can use, a tracking pixel (script) on our none Sitecore sites, however, I am not finding any documentation about this. Please point me in the right direction. -JMT

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking about using the Path Analyzer or how to use a Tracking Pixel? These are also pretty vague questions. Try asking questions that are a bit more focused and specific about what you are looking for.

Comment: **"I am interested in using Path Analyzer"** I want to use path analyzer to see traffic across both my Sitecore site and my none Sitecore sites. I was told you can do this by using a Sitecore tracking pixel on the none Sitecore sites and report back to Path Analyzer.

Comment: Maybe you want to track external site using FXM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Federated eXperience Manager: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/federated_experience_manager/a_functional_overview_of_fxm

FXM allows you to capture visitor information across sites.

You must add a JavaScript tag to every page though.

Comment: This looks like what was briefly described to me. Although on this page it specifically states that FXM does not currently support Path Analyzer. Thank you for the assistance this answers my question. I will have to do  some more reading/testing.  https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/federated_experience_manager/configuring/the_requirements_and_limitations_of_fxm